# Image sequence to animation with motion trail?

Tags: video, images, conversion, visual-effects

Let's say, I have an image sequence - here is an example of generating such a sequence in `bash`, using ImageMagick `convert`:

```bsh
for i in $(seq 1 10); do fname=$(printf "circle_%02d.png" $i); x=$((30+10*$i)); sz=$((10+2*$i)); magick convert -size 300x300 xc:LavenderBlush2 -stroke SeaGreen -fill PaleGreen -strokewidth 2 -draw "translate $x,$x circle 0,0 $sz,0" $fname; echo $fname; done
```

Then I can use ImageMagick to create an animated .gif out of this image sequence:

```bsh
magick convert -delay 20 circle*.png -loop 0 animcircle.gif
```

I have posted these images to https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dLLl.jpg ; and the gif (<sub>unfortunately, I cannot link to the same animcircle.gif I already posted on imgur, so I have to upload again ... Someone should invent some sort of a technology, where you could just upload once, and then use a link to show an image on webpage - it would be amazing!</sub>) looks like this:

[image: animation]

So, what happens here, is that the images are appended one after another as frames "verbatim", and we get the impression of animation.

What I would want to do however, is some sort of a motion-trail:

- First image gets added as video frame as-is/verbatim
- Second frame becomes something like 0.9*first_image + second_image - so I have some "ghost trail" of first image in second frame
- Third frame becomes something like 0.8*first_image + 0.9*second_image + third_image - so I have "ghost trail" of first and second images in third frame,
- Etc

This can be tricky, since adding the background pixels will definitely make the background color saturate, and I'm not sure what techniques can be used to make that less obvious - so ideally, I'd rather have a tool or library have some sort of handling for that.

I'd like to know, if this is possible to do in command line tools such as `ffmpeg` - or if there are Python libraries that allow doing something like this? I'd like to ultimately create an `.mp4` video - but converting image sequence to "motion-trailed" image sequence is also fine (since image-sequence-to-mp4 is standard practice with `ffmpeg` and similar tools)

Comment: Found something, that might work, but needs compiling from source and OpenCV: https://ao2.it/it/blog/2015/10/01/automatic-motion-trail-effect-opencv -> https://git.ao2.it/experiments/opencv_trail_effect.git/ (but IIRC, opencv is mostly used to manipulate live camera feed, I need something that can process either image sequence, or video file)

Answer (score 1):

Well you've already identified imagemagick & ffmpeg as the tools to achieve this so I think you're just a bit of head-scratching and experimentation away from success.

As you're generating the circles programmatically anyway, can you not generate the trail at the same time using alpha transparency?

I don't know if it would come out to a one-liner on the command line but certainly a short bash or python loop would do it easily, just build up from drawing the "oldest" circle at maximum transparency with each Nth circle (while n<i) drawn on top until you draw the current one.

That would be easier than generating "single ball" images and then stacking them transparently, although using imagemagick to make the background colour transparent and then stacking frames transparently on top of a blank background colour would likely achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks @JohnU - "As you're generating the circles programmatically anyway, can you not generate the trail at the same time using alpha transparency?" - that was just an example; I have a sets images where I do not have that kind of control (might as well be photographs), which is why I was wondering about a tool/library that already does this ...

Comment: Ah, OK - in that case, I'd say imagemagick is definitely going to be the tool for the job just stacking with alpha/transparency. You could "chain" the process so that the latest image is stacked on top of the last-generated one in the series rather than re-stack 10 images each time.